# Any way to symlink an NFS folder on a NTFS drive on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs, nfs

I am using Windows 7 and have successfully mounted an nfs drive using the Windows NFS Client. I would now link to symlink (or create a junction in different terminology) a folder to a location on a native NTFS drive. Is this at all possible or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mklink /d` to create a directory entry that point to a network share.  I haven't tested with NFS.

Note: you need to run this with elevated permissions

Comment: I think mklink only works on local drives.

Comment: Not true. I tested before posting.  We use it in production

Comment: Still working on Windows 10